# How to stretch a Border to fill the width of a ListViewItem?

Tags: wpf, layout, listviewitem

I have a `ListView` as follows:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding SerialNumbers}" SelectionMode="Multiple" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border Background="Red" Padding="14 5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Text="{Binding Number}" />
                <behaviours:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <behaviours:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonUp">
                        <behaviours:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.SerialNumberSelectedCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
                    </behaviours:EventTrigger>
                </behaviours:Interaction.Triggers>
            </Border>
         </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

I want the `Border` to take the full width as the `ListViewItem`, but it is not happening. I've tried adding `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"` to the `ListView`, `Border`, and the `TextBlock`. It isn't working. It currently looks like this.

[image: border not stretching to full width]

How can I stretch the Border to get the full width of the `ListViewItem`.

I want to achieve this because I have a *MouseLeftButtonUp* event linked to the `Border`, which will call a command. As the `Border` is only the red part, it will only be called on clicking the red part. I want it to be called on clicking the total width of the `ListViewItem`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43967046/wpf-listview-right-border-cut-off Does this helps you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, the cleanest way to achieve it is to set `HorizontalContentAlignment` to the `ListViewItem`. You can easily achieve this using a style, like this:

```
<ListView>
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Border Background="Red" >
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
      </Border>
     </DataTemplate>
   </ListView.ItemTemplate>
   <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
     <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
       <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
     </Style>
   </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
 </ListView>
```

Comment: Yes, it worked. It was such an easy solution and I totally missed it. Guess, I'm coding for too long to think straight. Thanks anyway. :)